# UTD 2052 oscilloscope: read data from .sav file

Tags: oscilloscope, data, binary

I just recently got an oscilloscope and was happy to try it out. Now I have a problem with reading the data. The model I am using is the UTD2052 50 Mhz scope.

I can save the data to a USB drive in the format .SAV (file is in [drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19wGKD6tpcHn-gJO2bQ3vKli09ajNdcbZ/view?usp=sharing) link). Now I can't seem to find any software to convert this file into Excel or CSV. The only software that works is WaveAnalyzer; screenshot:

[image: Image from Wave analyzer].

But I need the raw data. Any ideas how to open the file?

Comment: text editor perhaps

Comment: nope only crazy stuff :  ® ® ® ® ® ¯ ¯ ¯ ® ® ® ° ¯ ° ° ° ± ± ° ° ± ± ± ² ± ² ± ³ ± ³

Comment: not crazy stuff ... binary data

Comment: but how can you read it?

Comment: you can use python, C++, C#, VB, etc. .... almost any programming language that is able to read binary data from a file

Comment: okay I get that. But I can't find out how? Can you provide me with some code example...

Comment: I tried opening with python and got only rubish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea whether there exists a way of decoding that (Windows ME/XP-era?) proprietary binary format, but if you are desperate for some numerical data you can use WebPlotDigitizer to extract data.

Eg.

[image]

You may have more patience in selecting points or tweaking the autoextract settings than I did.

Comment: Okay thank how exactly did you load in the data?

Comment: I used the image you posted.